# Focus on next paragraph in contenteditable div / Summernote

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, summernote

I am using Summernote but replicating the Medium editor.

When inserting images, I only allow them to be inserted into their own paragraph tag. No text can be mixed in side paragraph tags with an image.

I give each paragraph with an image inside a class of 'has-image'. What I now want to do it not allow the user to enter any text inside of the paragraph if it has that class.

If they try to click inside the tag it will instead focus to the next paragraph.

Any help how to do this? I have tried triggering a click on the next paragraph but no luck:

```
$(document).on('click', '.has-image', function() {
    $(this).next('p').click();
});
```

I can set the text of the next paragraph so I know its selecting fine but cant think of a way to actually place the cursor inside.

JSFiddle as example: http://jsfiddle.net/vXnCM/5583/

Answer (score 1):

U may need to work with `Range`

```
$(document).on('click', '.has-image', function() {

    r = document.createRange()
    r.setStart($(this).next('p')[0],0);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(r);
});
```

NOTE: It only works for most modern browsers except IE.

For IE capability, Check https://code.google.com/archive/p/ierange/

Comment: Hmm, looks half right. http://jsfiddle.net/vXnCM/5584/ Thats an updated fiddle, if I click the image then it works, but click either side into the p tag itself still allow the user to enter text. Not sure if the standard behaviour can be overwritten. Not fussed about it < 10

Comment: only other solution I came with is to give the image a width greater than the containing p tag and then adjust its margin left. This way the user cannot click into the p tag at all.